# How to create salesforce login page inside android view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, salesforce, pager

I am newbie in exploring `Salesforce` sdk.

I have been looking for salesforce android sdk, I found to implement sdk we need to extend `SalesforceActivity` \ `SalesforceExpandableListActivity` \ `SalesforceListActivity`. But what if I need to show login in screen on one of tab of view pager, as view pager doesnt allow to insert activity and salesforce sdk doesnt have any base fragments class to extend.

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to get URL of Login Page?. If so you can open it in webview. THat webview can be part of one of the tab.

Comment: @SuhasK as i said I am newbie in this salesforce sdk, I didnot got any such thing here.

Comment: @SuhasK can I edit or put default values in the login page in the webview?

Answer (score 2):

Before posting the answer for your question, i would like to share few things about Salesforce and Android integration.

As [Salesforce Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK) per this To begin learning about the Salesforce Mobile SDK, follow this path.

- Watch the webinar [Building Mobile Apps with the Salesforce Mobile
  SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/mobile_SDK)
- Complete  [Mobile SDK Trail](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/trail/mobile_sdk_intro)
- Download the [Mobile SDK Development Guide](https://bitly.com/1vwq1rL)

However, the SDK is meant mostly for starting new apps, so you'll have some work ahead of you integrating it into an existing application. The main things you want are the oAuth 2.0 User-Agent login and REST wrappers.

You may also find this app useful -- Tomgersic put it together for a presentation at Dreamforce '11, which was shortly before the Mobile SDK for Android came out, so he wrote the oAuth and REST stuff in [GitHub](https://github.com/tomgersic/DreamforcengerHunt). Might be a simpler starting point for you

Here you can find a basic Salesforce - android [app](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/interfacing-salesforce-with-android.html) interaction which helps you further [Salesforce Mobile SDK - Eclipse Setup and Android App](http://blog.crmscience.com/2013/01/salesforce-mobile-sdk-eclipse-android.html)

Also, if you want, the Dreamforce session is on Youtube here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTNRO24-s7g&noredirect=1)

**Note:** this is exactly not an answer for the question, but it may help for you to proceed further.

Thanks !!